# TS1005 error with Angular2 - Problems with setup

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm working through the tour of heroes tutorial for Angular2 and working through the [http section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) and recently got this error from my `hero.service.ts` file:

**ERROR:**

```
app/hero.service.ts(12,23): error TS1005: '(' expected.
app/hero.service.ts(12,30): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

By running this code:

**Code:**

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http }   from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Hero }            from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

private headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private heroesUrl: 'app/heroes'; //URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
        .then(() => this.getHeroes());
}

getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
        .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
return this.http
    .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers:       
this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
 }

delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => null)
    .catch(this.handleError);
 }

update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
 const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
 return this.http
     .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
     .toPromise()
     .then(() => hero)
     .catch(this.handleError);
} 
}
```

At first I thought it was a mistyping but after checking several times and not seeing an answer I copied and pasted the answer from their plunkr and am still getting the same error message.

So presumably my implementation of TypeScript is not being implemented correctly.

My package.json file reads like this:

**package.json:**

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.2.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.2",
"typings":"^1.3.2"
}
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

My operating system is Windows10.

Thank you.

Comment: is this all of the hero.service.ts? If not, please update and add all code in hero.service.ts file.

Comment: Are you sure you copy and pasted that?

Comment: I just added the entire file.  Before I was only showing up to line 13,  where the error was occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes'; //URL to web api
```

Or

```
private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private heroesUrl: string = 'app/heroes'; //URL to web api
```